# 0x80004005 - Cannot complete this action. errors after applying June 2016 CU to SharePoint 2013 via Windows Update

Tags: 2013, cumulative-update

After applying the June 2016 Cumulative Update via Windows Update in my QA farm I'm constantly getting

```
"Cannot complete this action. Please try again. <nativehr>0x80004005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>"
```

When attempting to browse to any page in my main web app.  Central Admin still to functions normally.

What's confusing me is that this appears intermittent.  One minute the site will load fine, the next it returns this error.

If I run `IISReset` on the app server the site will work again for a minute or two before returning to these errors.

Windows Event Viewer and SharePoint ULS logs aren't showing much information beyond reiterating that this error is occurring.

Does anyone have experience with this type of issue in SharePoint?

Comment: How many servers in farm? Did you run the psconfig wizard after install? Also check the status of databases from central admin.. Upgrade ...review database status

Comment: One WFE , two App, and one database server in the farm.  All databases report "No action required."  CU and PSCONFIGUI were both run on all three SharePoint servers in the farm.

Comment: **The other change made this week was to enable remote blob storage on the sql server for the main content database. Not sure whether that would be a factor here.

Comment: I just found this error in the logs...its possibly contributing to this issue.  Investigating now.  

`File 62197f40-3369-4c78-8c20-1d7d0fa635b7 has is stored in SQL remote blob storage, but required software is not on the web front end. 1600949d-44f4-9068-ecc8-ff4a284399ce1`

Comment: You need to install rbs client library on all web servers. I think that what is missing

Comment: Here is link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631.aspx#library please let me know if that works

Comment: I added that as answer if your marked it answer so that other n I get benifits from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a part of rbs configuration there is one setting which you have to perform on the web server called "install rbs client library on each web server". I think that is ur problem. Please install it and test

> you must install RBS client library on all web servers in the SharePoint farm. The RBS client library is installed only one time per web server, but RBS is configured separately for each associated content database. The client library consists of a client-side dynamic link library (DLL) that is linked into a user application, and a set of stored procedures that are installed on SQL Server.

Please this for more info:https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631.aspx#library

Answer (score 0):

[Waqas Sarwar MSCE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/21563/waqas-sarwar-mcse) had the solution.  I missed installing the RBS client on my app server.  After installing and rebooting all servers in the farm including the database server the sites resumed normal functionality.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may occur if a file that the Windows Product Activation (WPA) requires is damaged or missing. This behavior occurs if one or both of the following conditions are true: A third-party backup utility or an antivirus program interferes with the installation of Windows XP.

Greetings,
Peter